# How to apply custom css to android Webview when URL is from internet server?

Tags: android, html, css, wordpress, webview

I'm showing my wordpress blog posts on my android app.

`Giving wordpress url inside webview`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        // Enable Javascript
         WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
         webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.myblog.com/start/");        
    }
```

But I want to remove footer block for that I just want to add

```
.footer{
diplay:none
}
```

How can I add this custom css code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the page is loaded, run some JavaScript, something like:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0].style.display = 'none';");
```

should do it. On Android 4.4, you can use the [WebView.evaluateJavaScript API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript%28java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29).

Detecting when the page is loaded such that this JavaScript will work is tricky. The most reliable way to do it would be to install a [JavaScript Interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) that calls back to Java when the `onload` event is fired in your HTML. You'd want to have something like this in your Java, before your first call to `WebView.loadUrl`:

```
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onload() {

        // This is executed on a background thread, so post back to UI thread.
        mWebView.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:...");
            }

        });

    }

}, "android");
```

And then in your HTML:

```
<body onload="window.android.ready();">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: where exactly code should be?
 `//Load url in webview
mWebView.loadUrl(url);        mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsById('footer-wrapper')[0].style.display = 'none';");`

Comment: Added some thoughts that should help you.

Comment: Anything in logcat? Are you sure that 'footer' is the class name of the element you want to hide? Does it have an id instead?

Comment: `<body onload="window.android && window.android.ready();">` is fail safe

Comment: if it's an external url, how are you supposed to add onload="window.android.ready();" to the body tag of the html?

Comment: The issue here is , first the footer is loaded and then removed. Its displayed for a second before being removed. Is there a way to remove it before loading?

Answer (score -2):

Another trick is to set custom user agent string for webview

```
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("foo");
```

and in javascript

```
if (window.navigator.userAgent == "foo") {
  // do whatever you want :)
}
```

If you want to preserve default user agent string, you can append "foo" to it and use`window.navigator.userAgent.includes('foo')` in javascript