# on android app webview want to hide footer?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

in android app using `WebView` to show my blog.

> but if I'm accessing it using mobile app using `WebView`,
>
> I want to hide footer div , how can I do it?

I can hide anything in wordpress css

by doing this

```
.footer pageId-34{
display:none}
```

But how to do it on `WebView`?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124770, no?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply custom css to android Webview when URL is from internet server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124770/how-to-apply-custom-css-to-android-webview-when-url-is-from-internet-server)

Comment: I have commented issue what I tried please check