# My first android app.. custom css

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an app with a webview of facebook.com, i want to load custom css but i don't know how. I searched on Google but found old tutorials and i read that it has changed in Android Studio 2.0

Here is my code:

```
private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
```

Comment: Check [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585210/webview-add-local-css-file-to-an-html-page) and Check [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124770/how-to-apply-custom-css-to-android-webview-when-url-is-from-internet-server)

Comment: `Android Studio 2.0` has nothing to do with the Android Development. You can still use eclipse and develop android apps.

Comment: place your Css file in Assets folder and in webview give path of your css to load..

Comment: @RameshKumar i don't have an Assets folder. I'm using android studio 2.0

Comment: if don't have the create an assets folder in main folder (src->main->assets)

Comment: @RameshKumar thanks. i got the assets folder now but how do i give path to my css to load?

Comment: refer this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585210/webview-add-local-css-file-to-an-html-page?lq=1

Comment: @RameshKumar this is what i got now: https://justpaste.it/to68 ... it doesn't work :( I'm trying to load https://www.facebook.com/ with custom css.. i have the style.css stored in my assets folder